# Get values from 2 tables based on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider below tables

Job Table

```
JobID   AnswerID   UserID
  1        1,2       1
  2        2,3       2
  3        1,3       3
```

Answer Table

```
AnswerID  Answer    QuestionID
   1      Clean          1
   2      Install        1
   3      Other          2
```

For this I need to get the result as below

```
JobID     Answer           UserID
  1       Clean,Install      1
  2       Install,Other      2
  3       Clean,Other        3
```

Please help to write MSSQL query for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing a list of ids as a comma separated list. This is a really bad idea for several reasons:

- Storing numbers as strings is a bad idea.
- You cannot define foreign key relationships.
- SQL does not have great support for strings.
- Any attempt to join to the original table will be inefficient, because of the type conversion.
- Such a structure violates the idea that a column contains a single value.

There is a proper way to store lists in a relational database. It is called a "table". You want a junction table with one row per job and answer. I would call it `JobAnswers`.

With the proper data structure, your query would be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use subqueries like this:

```
SELECT job.jobID, 
(SELECT answer.answer FROM answer WHERE answer.answerID IN (job.answerID)) as answers, 
job.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Gordon Linoff I do understand we have no control over what we inherit from previous developers.

here is what you require to do:

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
                  (
             JobID INT, AnswerID VARCHAR(10), UserID INT
                  );


INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
       (1, '1,2', 1
       ),
       (2, '2,3', 2
       ),
       (3, '1,3', 3
       );

CREATE TABLE #temp2
                   (
             AnswerID INT, Answer VARCHAR(10), QuestionID INT
                   );

INSERT INTO #temp2
VALUES
       (1, 'Clean', 1
       ),
       (2, 'Install', 1
       ),
       (3, 'Other', 2
       );
```

Query:

```
SELECT #temp.JobID,
       (
          SELECT #temp2.Answer
          FROM #temp2
          WHERE #temp2.AnswerID = SUBSTRING(#temp.AnswerID, 1, CHARINDEX(',', #temp.AnswerID)-1)
       )+','+
       (
       SELECT #temp2.Answer
       FROM #temp2
       WHERE #temp2.AnswerID = SUBSTRING(#temp.AnswerID, CHARINDEX(',', #temp.AnswerID)+1, LEN(#temp.AnswerID)-1)
       ) AS Answer, 
       #temp.UserID
FROM #temp;
```

Result:

[image]